# Combining <? extends ClassE> and <? super ClassB>

Tags: java, generics, extends, super

I understand how ? extends .. and ? super .. work on their own and which generic types are possible, but I just can't understand how the following is possible with this hierarchy:

-> means extends

Classes are X (lowest), A to E (highest)

Interface is F

X -> A (implements F) -> B -> C -> E (implements F)

also D -> E

```
public class Node<T extends ClassE> {
    private T info;

    public T getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo(T info) {
        this.info = info;
    }
}

public static void main (String [] args){

    Node<? super ClassB> n2 = new Node<ClassC>(); 
// this makes sense, since Node accepts below E and above B

    InterfaceF i2 = n2.getInfo();
// how? Not only outside of <? extends E> but also getting value even though 
// <? super B> is defined above, what's up with PECS?

    n2.setInfo(new ClassX());
// also.. how? I'm setting a class that's out of the allowed range + 
// seemingly violating the PECS for <? extends E>
}
```

As you can see, I'm totally confused when it comes to combining them and it's quite surprising for me having those declarations pass the compiler without problems.
I read somewhere that a combination of both bounds isn't possible in Java, but how does that work then?

Comment: Are you sure this `Node<? super ClassB> n2 = new Node<ClassC>();` compiles? Reference n2 requires `Node` with parametric type B or higher, whereas you are trying to pass C which is lower than B at inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: I didn't assign any values to test it, but I'm perfectly able to execute the program, I'm 100% sure

Comment: About the hierarchy, the E is the highest and X is the lowest, sorry for the confusion.
So A extends B, B extends C, C extends E

Comment: PECS is just a memory device, the actual Java language rules are abstract and do not refer to concrete patterns such as a producer/consumer relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I do not know the concrete type inference rules but explain to my best understanding.

Regarding `InterfaceF i2 = n2.getInfo()` - since `Node<T extends E>` it is assured that `Node.getInfo()` returns something `extends E`. According to your description `E implements F`. As such it is ensured that `T extends E` will also `implement F`. Therefore `Node.getInfo() = T extends E implements F`. So `n2.getInfo() implements F` is fine.

Regarding `n2.setInfo(new ClassX())` - I do not have a formal-like explanation for this as above but let's try to think about it: Basically you `Node<? super ClassB>` tells everyone to *expect* **at most** `ClassB` as its lowest for the `Node`'s content. However, since `ClassX` transitively inherits `ClassB` it is perfectly valid since it will satisfy all interface guarantees posed by `? super ClassB`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's the approach I tried on another example and it was fantastic.
It's especially helpful since it's like step-by-step and easy to apply to other scenarios aswell.

Answer (score 2):

The first line `InterfaceF i2 = n2.getInfo();` compiles because the lower-bounded wildcard still retains the bound on the type variable itself. Since the type variable has an upper bound `ClassE`, `getInfo()` still returns a `ClassE`. Since `ClassE` implements `InterfaceF`, the assignment compiles.

In other words, we could imagine that when you did `Node<? super ClassB>` you implicitly actually did something like (made-up syntax) `Node<? extends ClassE & super ClassB>`. The type argument to the `Node` is both a supertype of `ClassB` *and* a subtype of `ClassE`.

This is similar to how `Node<?>` is implicitly the same as `Node<? extends ClassE>`.

The way this is actually specified is a little bit complicated, but it's in [capture conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10). Capture conversion is the process whereby the compiler takes a type with wildcards and treats it as if it was a type without wildcards, for the purpose of determining subtyping.

> Let `G` name a generic type declaration with *n* type parameters `A1,...,An` with corresponding bounds `U1,...,Un`.
>
> There exists a *capture conversion* from a parameterized type `G<T1,...,Tn>` to a parameterized type `G<S1,...,Sn`, where, for *1 ≤ i ≤ n* :
>
> - [...]
> - If `Ti` is a wildcard type argument of the form `? super Bi`, then `Si` is a fresh type variable whose upper bound is `Ui[A1:=S1,...,An:=Sn]` and whose lower bound is `Bi`.

In other words, `Si` (the type argument after capture conversion corresponding to `? super ClassB`) gains its lower bound from the bound of the wildcard and its upper bound from the bound of the type variable declaration.

The second line `n2.setInfo(new ClassX());` compiles because `ClassX` is a subclass of `ClassB` so it's implicitly convertible to it. We could imagine that `n2` was a `Node<ClassB>` and it might be more obvious why this line compiles:

```
Node<ClassB> n2 = ...;
n2.setInfo(new ClassX());
```

`setInfo` accepts `ClassB` as well as any subtype of `ClassB`.

Also, with respect to this:

> I read somewhere that a combination of both bounds isn't possible in Java, but how does that work then?

The type system in the compiler does a lot of things that we can't explicitly do ourselves. Another good example (although unrelated) is type inference with anonymous classes:

```
int num = Objects.requireNonNull(new Object() {int num = 42;}).num;
System.out.println(num); // 42
```

It compiles because type inference is allowed to infer that the type argument to `T` of `requireNonNull` is the anonymous object type, even though we could never provide that type as an explicit type argument ourselves.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to explain it in-depth. 
I made some testings and the problem was that I didn't look at the type of the method. Since the reading methods (like getInfo) require the Upper-bound of my type T, n2.getInfo() only can be of type E or lower.
Therefore I can take anything above like
Object i2 = n2.getInfo(); and it will work 
Similar for setInfo() which is a writing operation where I need to take the lower bound.

Also, what do you mean by "anonymous object type" ? Do you mean the anonymous classes like Object$1 which have their own type?

Comment: *"Do you mean the anonymous classes like Object$1 which have their own type?"* Yeah, when you write an anonymous object like `new Object() {}` you are implicitly declaring a new class, but the anonymous class has no name so there's no way to refer to it. In my example, there would be no way to access `num` outside of the anonymous object other than what type inference is doing. (My example isn't code which anyone should ever use. It's just an example of a weird compiler quirk.)

Comment: Alright now I understand. I thought there could be some benefits I didn't see (besides the obvious ones from anonymous classes).
Pretty interesting example.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
    public interface F {}
    public static class E implements F {}
    public static class D extends E {}
    public static class C extends E {}
    public static class B extends C {}
    public static class A extends B implements F {}
    public static class X extends A {}

    public static class Node<T extends E> {
        private T info;
        public T getInfo() {return info;}
        public void setInfo(T info) {this.info = info;}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node<? super B> n = new Node<C>(); // C is superclass of B = OK
        F i = n.getInfo(); // node type = B|C|E all these types implements F (since E implements F) = OK
        n.setInfo(new X()); // X has supertypes A,B,C,E = can be casted to B and so satisfy <? super B>
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also explain what you have done or changed? Explanation is often more helpful than a code only answer.

Comment: @Zabuza all the code above main method follows OP's inheritance, main method has comments which explains well what is going on, so why non-code lines?

Comment: Solid answer and straight to the point, it took me some time to figure out that every get - operation requires and upperbound itself and every set-operation requires a lowerbound. 

Combined with your explanation I guess everything became clear.